# How to get each row from a TDBGrid in c++

Tags: c++builder, tdbgrid

I am using embarcadero c++ builder and i want to copy the result of a query contained in a DBGrid, is there a way to get each row from the DBGrid?

Comment: C++ does not have a TDBGrid. There are tags available for C++Builder. Please use them instead of the generic C++ tag.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "copy the result," as well as what type of database you are using. A [TDBGrid](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid) is typically used to display and edit data visually. It's not the most efficient way to get information from a database and put it into a data structure.

So, if what you want is to (non-visually) do some action for each row of a SQL result set, you should probably use a [TSQLQuery](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLQuery). This object has useful methods and properties (i.e., First(), Next(), and Eof) that allow you to iterate through the result set.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the result from the `TDBGrid` directly; you get it from the `TDataSet` attached to the `TDataSource` that is connected to the `TDbGrid`. IOW, you read it directly from the `TQuery/TADOQuery/TSQLQuery` that you use to execute the query. As you've not mentioned which DBMS and data components you're using, it's impossible to be more specific.

You can find the component that is executing the query at design-time (in the IDE) by clicking on the grid and inspecting it's `DataSource` property in the Object Inspector's *Properties* page, which will give you the name of the `TDataSource` component. Clicking on that datasource and inspecting it's `DataSet` property will give you the name of the query component which is running the SQL statement. You can read from that component to retrieve the data that is returned by executing the statement.